Sistema de cardápio online
Boa tarde pessoal! Tudo certo?
Há alguns meses comecei meus estudos em programação e com a ajuda de alguns cursos, criei um sistema web, onde os restaurantes conseguem adicionar informações como: logo, descrição, horário de funcionamento e também conseguem editar o seu próprio cardápio.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como gero uma página de cardápio para mais de uma empresa? Quero que o painel (exemplo: cardapio.com.br) seja usado por todas empresas (já consigo fazer isso usando o idempresa que é passado no localstorage na hora do login), mas que cada empresa tenha um link para seu cardápio.
Ex: cardapio.com.br/empresa1 ou empresa1.cardapio.com.br
Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?
Utilizo javascript, nodejs e mysql.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
